# update child component after an async call in parent

Tags: react-native

I am trying to update a child component from parent. The parent component initially makes an async call to get value and the value was to be reflected in child but refused so far. It only shows the initial value of 0 set in the Parent.

ChildComponent.js

```
const ChildComponent = ({
  value
}) => {
  return (
      <View>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </View>
  );
};


export default ChildComponent;
```

Parent.js

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getValue() {
      const { totalBorrowed } = await Service.getBorrowDetails();
       console.log(totalBorrowed); //resolves well
      updateValue(totalBorrowed);
      console.log(value); //shows the correct value
    }

    getValue(); // tried .then().catch()
  }, [value]);

  return (
        <View>
          <ChildComponent
            value={value}
          />
        </View>
  );
};
export default Parent;
```

even though the value has been updated, ChildComponent shows 0 only, the initial value.

Comment: This code is correct. Have you tried running this simplified version? Perhaps the problem is in your actual code and not what you shared?

Comment: `updateValue(totalBorrowed); console.log(value);` These two lines next to each other show a lack of understanding. `updateValue` schedules an update of value for sometime in the future. `value` will not be updated synchronously, so your comments are wrong.

Comment: @windowsill I am pretty sure the values i am seeing in my console log are correct but if they are being printed in the future could be a case. I am still learning.

Comment: What are the logs